# MDBoxLayout -> Widget width and height doesn't work ! kivy/kivymd

Tags: kivy, height, width, kivymd

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Widget:
        size_hint_y: 5
        height: 100
        width: 100
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Ellipse:
                size: self.width / 3 , self.width / 3
                pos: ( self.width - ( self.width / 3 ) ) / 2 , self.height - 100
                source: 'cat-1.jpg'
                angle_start: 0
                angle_end: 360

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: scroll
            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: profile
                text: "Profile"
                elevation: 10
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "account-card-details-outline"
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting `adaptive_height` of `MDBoxLayout` to `True`. Also you should briefly describe the problem you are facing along with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.